# Check if Dictionary(Of String, String) is Nothing or Empty in a single statement

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, null

I know the statement [String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) which I use regulary.
But now I'm wondering if I could use something similar for [Dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

My Current Code:

```
Public Property ExpectedResults As Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)

Public Function SomeMethod() As Boolean
'Some code

If (IsNothing(ExpectedResults)) Then
    Return True
End If
If ExpectedResults.Count = 0 Then
   Return True
End If

For Each key As String In ExpectedResults.Keys
    'If Regex Matches value
        Return True
     'End If
Next

Return False    
End Sub
```

Is it possible to replace those `2 Ifs` with `1 single statement`? Or am I searching for something that doesn't exist?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You want to check if your Dictionary is NOT nothing and also contains items? In this case I would go with

```
If Not IsNothing(ExpectedResults) AndAlso ExpectedResults.Count > 0 Then
    Return True
End If
```

Comment: Won't work. 'True' must be returned if `ExpectedResults` is Nothing or has no keys.  Even the statement `If IsNothing(ExpectedResults) AndAlso ExpectedResults.Count > 0 Then` doesn't pass when ExpectedResults Is Nothing

Comment: Ok, `If IsNothing(ExpectedResults) OrElse ExpectedResults.Count = 0` might be what you're looking for!?

Comment: Your Questions was a little unclear regarding the expected result, cause you checked if the Dictionary is nothing or has at least one item in your If statements...

Comment: Indeed that was it. How could i have missed a statement as simple as `OrElse` . #Bows_Head_In_Disgrace#

Comment: thanks for mentionning the error in the question. I didn't realise i made a typo there!

Answer (score 1):

The [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) makes it pretty tidy:

```
 If ExpectedResults?.Count > 0 Then
    Return True
 End If
```